# JavaScript regex to test if multiline string ends with a carriage return

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the regex to test whether a multiline string ends with a carriage return?

This is what I have so far but I'm not convinced it would work for all the different types of line endings (Windows, Linux and Mac):

```
/[\r\n]$/.test(myMultiLineString)
```

Please could someone confirm whether this would work or not? If not, please provide the correct approach.

### Edit

Changed regex from `/\r?\n$/` to `/[\r\n]$/` (see comments).

Comment: Are you using the term *carriage return* in the meaning *line break*?

Comment: `/[\r\n]$/` is more accurate

Comment: these strings could be loaded from file OR they could just be something like 'hello\nthere\n' - solution needs to cope with both - hope that clarifies

Comment: why is /[\r\n]$/ more accurate? thanks

Comment: yah i wondered about the multi line flag, is it necessary?

Comment: It is because on some OS e.g Mac, by default, uses a single carriage return ( `<CR>` ), represented as `\r`.

Comment: It is unclear what you really need to do. Test and decide if there is vertical whitespace at the end of the string? Remove/replace all of them? What to do if there are several linebreaks at the end of the string? Please provide some sample strings and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using this regex:

```
/[\r\n]$/
```

Which means there has to be `\n` at the end **optionally** preceded by `\r` or `<CR>`.

Some editors on earlier version of Mac were using just `\r` as line break character hence if text is edited there then above regex will return false.

Hence it is bit more accurate to use this form:

```
/[\r\n]$/
```

This will match either `\n` or `\r` at the end irrespective of what comes before.

[Reference on Mac OS Line ending](https://superuser.com/questions/439440/did-mac-os-lion-switch-to-using-line-feeds-lf-n-for-line-breaks-instead-of)

Comment: Would this form `(?:\r?\n|\r)$` be the same?

Comment: @sln - hi there - this works very well in all my tests, can you explain what it is doing please - i understand that it works for \r\n \r and \n - but i don't understand why it starts with ?:

Comment: @danday74: `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group.